# Form Validation fails, still it submits in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

For my code below the javascript validates the input, but I can't stop it from submitting. How can I stop it. Here is my code.

```
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function validateForm() {
            [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[name^=name]'), function (el, p, l) {
                if (el.name.indexOf('_var') > -1) {
                    if (el.value === "NA" && l[p - 1].value !== "NA") {
                        alert("Name_var must be filled out");
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
        Name:
        <input type="text" name="name25"> Name1:
        <input type="text" name="name25_var">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please re format your code with proper indenting.

Comment: i see it is correctly indented.

Comment: Because @loxxy did it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to keep your code, I will try declaring a variable to submit the form only if not exists any kind of error, something like that:

```
function validateForm() {
    var existError = false;

    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[name^=name]'), function (el, p, l) {
        if (el.name.indexOf('_var') > -1) {
            if (el.value === "NA" && l[p - 1].value !== "NA") {
                alert("Name_var must be filled out");
                existError = true;
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        return existError;
    });
}
```

The problem is your sentence "return" is only to return from "forEach" BUT forEach is a function that never stop until loop all elements, if you want to stop at the moment that you find and error, then you should use [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/every):

```
function validateForm() {
        return [].every.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[name^=name]'), function(el, p, l) {
            if(el.name.indexOf('var') > 1 && el.value === "NA" && l[p - 1].value !== "NA") {
                alert('Name_var must be filled out');
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        });
    }
```

Funtional example:

```js
function validateForm() {
        return [].every.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[name^=name]'), function(el, p, l) {
            if(el.name.indexOf('var') > 1 && el.value === "NA" && l[p - 1].value !== "NA") {
                alert('Name_var must be filled out');
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        });
    }
```

```html
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
        Name:
        <input type="text" name="name25"> Name1:
        <input type="text" name="name25_var">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: I had a type mistake on name=^ and should be name^= .... try again please, now it's working for me.

Comment: I filled 'saurav' in name and 'NA' in name1 and submitted. it gave me the alert but still submits. Can you send the complete code which you are using.

Comment: I added the code using stackoverflow code snippet. It's working right for me so it should work right for you too.